# how to loop through array and extract another array data php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hi i have a multidimensional array and a parameter that may change frequently .
i made some code to extract data just for 3 level loop through array .
but i can't convert it to function that work in array_map or array_walk .
is it possible ?

sample array data :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test1"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test2"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test2"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test3"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test4"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test10"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(10)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test11"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(11)
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test12"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(12)
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test13"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(13)
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test14"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(14)
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test20"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(20)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test21"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(21)
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test22"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(22)
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test23"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(23)
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["loc"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(8) "test24"
      }
      ["rel"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(24)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is sample function that can loop 3 times
but i want make it dynamic loop through this array

```
foreach ( $data as $k => $v ) { 
    $cnt  = 0 ;
    foreach ( $data as $m => $n ) { 
        array_push($parents,$k);
        if ( !in_array($m,$parents)) { 
            foreach ( $data as $x => $y ) { 
                array_push($parents,$m);
                if ( !in_array($x,$parents)) { 
                    $hold[$k][$cnt] = array(
                        $k , $m , $x
                    );
                    $cnt++;
                }
            }
            $parents = deleteFromArray($parents , $m);
        }
    }
    $parents = deleteFromArray($parents , $k);
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question would probably be a simple `Yes`. The real question is, what do you try to accomplish?

Comment: i wanna to traverse array with a dynamic number . if you see that function i tried to create a stack and put node item in a path and create a set like this 
[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,1],[0,2,3] - [1,0,2],[1,0,3] - [1,2,3] - [2,0,1],[2,0,3] - [3,0,1][3,0,2]
if you choose a node in first section you can't choose that node in second section .choose node 0 in first the you sould select between 1,2,3 in second , and if you choose 0,1 in first and second , then you should choose from 2,3 in third select .